# I am unable to run a loop dependent on variable from function

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, callback

Okay so i've spent the last day trying to figure something out, I'm relatively new to coding so if its a mess I'm sorry. I'm currently working on a bot that requests a JSON, here is the code I have so far

```
 const request = require('request');

 const bodyParser = require('body-parser');


global.count = 10;

for (var i = 1; global.count === 10; i++) {

var options = {
  url: 'https://www.the100.io/api/v1/groups/2127/users?page=' + i, //Returns 10 entries per page, so loop is to navigate pages
  headers: {
  'Authorization': 'Token token="Hidden for Privacy"'
  }
}

function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var info = JSON.parse(body); //Also need a way to append to info as to add on as the loop progresses, still need to look that up though
    console.log(JSON.stringify(info, null, 1)); //Logs the body
    global.count = info.length; //Will return the value 10, until there are no more entries and then will terminate loop
  }
}

request(options, callback);//Sends request
}
//It just keeps running the loop and doesn't execute the request at the bottom which is what will make the loop terminate, I've tried many things with 
//callbacks and nothing has worked so far
```

I can't seem to be able to make the loop run properly, I didn't wanna ask for help but I am stuck I'm sad to say. Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: The loop termination condition is always true. `global.count = 10` **returns**  `10`, which is `true`. `=` is assignment, **`===`** is comparison. However, even if you did fix that, it would not work, because the callbacks cannot be executed before the loop terminates, but the loop can only terminate if a callback runs and sets the correct value. This article is very important for understanding JavaScript's processing model: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop .

Comment: your loop termination condition is always true because your assigning in the condition. change it to `global.count === 10` to fix that part. The other problem you'll then run in to is that your `request()`s will be asynchronous so the final request may finish before one of the other requests and then set `global.count = 0;` only to be overwritten by one of the previous requests. You should probably not attempt to do this in a loop, rather call a function that makes the request and then when that request completes, make the request with the next page and so on, until you have all the pages.

Comment: @Dymos: The callbacks will never be executed because the loop is blocking everything else.

Comment: @FelixKling ah yea good call.

Comment: @FelixKling So is there another way to get the same output I'm looking for?  From what I've read, my belief was a loop was the only way.

Comment: Loops are synchronous. If you want to call an async function repeatedly you should use indirect recursion. I.e. have the callback call the async function again if certain conditions are met.

Comment: @FelixKling That would be done with an if statement? Do you have a link to a site explaining indirect recursions so I don't have to bother you with questions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think Some what confusion in the question and explain clearly???

In Your writing for loop is continuously  repeating You want like that are some thing else..

in my thought it should be for navigation of page loading( every page contains 10)

```
global.count = 10;
for( var i = 1; i< =global.count; i++)
{
 -- Write Your code here ---
}
```

Comment: Its supposed to navigate through the pages but as @felixKling said it won't be able too because the function won't run because of the loop

Comment: @MGomeyy That's why i am puttig for loop like with condition you can try  above i am declaring for loop

Comment: The loop needs to stop when `info.length` doesn't equal 10, so what you said would't work in my case, thank you though

Comment: write condition in the response you got

Comment: var info = JSON.parse(body); //Also need a way to append to info as to add on as the loop progresses, still need to look that up though
    console.log(JSON.stringify(info, null, 1)); //Logs the body
    global.count = info.length;